# Flutter image doesn't appear on screen

Tags: flutter, image, user-interface, flutter-web

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: cocacola_bottle.jpg.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

This is the yaml file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

This is the page:

```
 class Signup extends StatelessWidget {
  const Signup({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          // first row first box
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
              height: 1040,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  image: AssetImage('cocacola_bottle.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, image the doesn't appear on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the full path:

```
image: AssetImage('assets/cocacola_bottle.jpg'),
```